# Twitter's Bootstrap - Form Inputs Too Thin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap to create the HTML/CSS for my website.  I run into a problem when creating the forms, however:

[image: screenshot of error]

As you can see the inputs are too skinny for the text.  I have tested with my own code, as well as copy/pasting the exact code from their documentation:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

I am including two resources:

```
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As far as I can tell they are loading correctly.  Am I missing a resource?

Comment: Have you inspected in Chrome Inspector or Firebug to see where the height is being overridden?

Comment: it is getting a height from you local css, look form inputs in you local css  and remove it. It is hard to guess just by a screenshot

Comment: I've tried tweaking a few things and I did fix it.  I am not sure what I did wrong, but I did do something incorrectly - it's not default behaviour.  (Also, I have no local CSS.)  EDIT: I will come back and update once I figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Damnit.  I was missing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of the document.

Comment: This also sometimes happens when you have a PHP error somewhere in your page; sometimes they appear before the doctype, meaning the browser doesn't acknowledge it. Although I'm sure the PHP error would be higher in a list of priorities ;P

Comment: Important detail : it's <!DOCTYPE html> , not <!DOCTYPE HTML> , this is not working in uppercase !

Answer (score 6):

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` fix did not work for me. But what helped was finding and removing following in our codebase:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Great! Had the same issue and this was the problem.

Comment: i have the same problem. Anyone has an explanation for this? I don't want to change such fundamental stuff.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and drove me mad for hours as the cause was completely invisible. I already had the `<!DOCTYPE html>` there and all the code was perfect. The problem turned out to be the text file encoding.

Using the linux 'file' command showed the source file coded as: "PHP script, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text".

Running 'more' on the file showed some garbage chars (ï»¿) at the start of the files. I created new files within linux and copied/pasted the code in and everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me was adding `class="form-control"` to the input.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I had the same problem and after weeks searching for a solution, this guy solved my problem!

[getting application.css to override bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437497/getting-application-css-to-override-bootstrap)

1 - create the file assets/stylesheets/**my_styles.css.scss**

2 - put the code bellow in **my_styles.css.scss** file:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=tel] {
height: 33px !important;}
```

3 - In assets/stylesheets/application.css, put this:

```
*= require my_styles
```

after bootstraps require...
in my case it is:

```
*= require font-awesome
*= require bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2
*= require_self
*= require my_styles
*= require_tree .
*/
```

Hope it helps someone in trouble!