# Ruby on Rails assets - where are files located

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am newbie using Ruby on Rails to develop simple app. I have included twitter-bootstrap-rails gem. In my site all files are included ect.

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap.css?body=1
```

But in assets folder I cant find twitter-bootstrap-static folder or bootstrap.css file.

I am reading about Rails Asset Pipeline. Can someone simplify it to me ?

Comment: If you want to browse gems source code use bundle show gem-name. For example if you run bundle show bootstrap-sass it will print the location of gem source code in my case output is /home/deep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0 . You can also open the entire source code for a gem using bundle show bootstrap-sass | xargs subl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst *your* assets are stored in the `/assets` folder, any assets appended by gems (such as `bootstrap`) are kept out of the local assets files (keeps it clean)

If you've included the [bootstrap gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails), you'd need to override the elements you wish to change in your own files, as explained here:

> [getting application.css to override bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437497/getting-application-css-to-override-bootstrap)

---

[**Asset Pipeline**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

The asset pipeline is a fancy name for a collection of directories, which share stylesheet, graphic & javascript data:

> The asset pipeline provides a framework to concatenate and minify or
>   compress JavaScript and CSS assets. It also adds the ability to write
>   these assets in other languages such as CoffeeScript, Sass and ERB

There's nothing special about these folders except Rails can `compile` them to make minified CSS & JS files

Comment: Thank you. Can You explain me where I can find that bootstrap.css. Is it loaded from CDN. Where do it exist in my project folder ?

Comment: It doesn't exist in your project folder (it's appended via the gem after you deploy the app). You'll have to override any elements you want in your `application.css`. If you want to edit `bootstrap.css`, you'll have to include it in your `assets` folder manually :)