# Bootstrap number input is too thin but text input is alright

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this following piece of code.

```
           <fieldset>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="number-of-properties">Number Of Properties</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input  id="number-of-properties" type="number" min=0>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </fieldset>
```

The number input is too thin and only half of the number is visible. I want the full number to be visible.

Comment: Add this "form-control" class to input tag.

Comment: doesnot work . I have tried lots of form-control and other classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter's Bootstrap - Form Inputs Too Thin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170305/twitters-bootstrap-form-inputs-too-thin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y23cv28y/) using the code from question but with few minor tweaks. It works fine in the fiddle. If this is not the solution you are looking for then please create a fiddle or plunker and post it here to show us the error you get and your expected result. Hope it helps.

```
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="number-of-properties">Number Of Properties</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="number-of-properties" type="number" min=0>
</div> </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your page? Also add "form-control" class to input element.

Comment: @SouravMukherjee , then it must some other class that must be interfering with bootstrap class. Use a debugger to identify what all classes are changing the attributes.

Comment: I also have <!DOCTYPE html>